Why am i getting a segmentation fault in a code for checking palindrome using linked list?
The statements for my questions are:
Write a program to determine whether a linked list is a palindrome or not.
**Input Format:
**
The first line contains integers separated by spaces representing the elements of the linked list.
The second line contains a single integer representing the length of the linked list.
**Output Format:
**
If the linked list is a palindrome, print "Palindrome".
If the linked list is not a palindrome, print "Not Palindrome".
I am getting a segmentation fault after using the following functions.
//The function for creating the nodes using array.
struct node* create(head){
    int n;
    printf("Enter the number of nodes in the linked list:");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int arr[n];
    printf("Enter the character for each node spearated by spaces:");
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        fscanf(stdin,"%d", &arr[i]);
    }
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        struct node* temp = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        temp->data = arr[i];
        temp->next = NULL;
        temp->prev=NULL;
        struct node* p;
        if(head==NULL){
            head=temp;
        }
        else{
            while (p->next!=NULL)
            {
                p=p->next;
            }
            p->next=temp;
            temp->prev=p;
        }
    }
}

//The function for checking palindrome

struct node* pallindrome(head){
    struct node* p = head;
    struct node* q = head;
    int count=0;
    while(q!=NULL){
        q=q->next;
        count++;
    }

    for(int i=0;i<(count/2);i++){
        if(p->data==q->data){
            p=p->next;
            q=q->prev;
            continue;
        }
        else{
            printf("Not Pallindrome");
            return;
        }
    }

    printf("Pallindrome");
}

I am getting Segmentation Fault in the above code after implementing the functions in the main function. I would appreciate any help.
The compiler adds in the following warnings:
pallindrome.c: In function 'create':
pallindrome.c:13:14: warning: type of 'head' defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int]
 struct node* create(head){
              ^~~~~~
pallindrome.c:28:16: warning: comparison between pointer and integer
         if(head==NULL){
                ^~
pallindrome.c:29:17: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
             head=temp;
                 ^
pallindrome.c: In function 'pallindrome':
pallindrome.c:42:14: warning: type of 'head' defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int]
 struct node* pallindrome(head){
              ^~~~~~~~~~~
pallindrome.c:43:22: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
     struct node* p = head;
                      ^~~~
pallindrome.c:44:22: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
     struct node* q = head;
                      ^~~~
pallindrome.c:59:13: warning: 'return' with no value, in function returning non-void
             return;
             ^~~~~~
pallindrome.c:42:14: note: declared here
 struct node* pallindrome(head){
              ^~~~~~~~~~~


Your function create, what does it return?

I also recommend you don't try to use a single structure for a linked list. Create a special "linked list" structure, which has pointers to both the head and tail nodes. Then of course the node structure themselves, which are separate from the list structure. This makes the abstraction easier to handle. And by using a separate tail pointer it's very easy to add nodes to both the head and the tail.

Oh, and in truct node* pallindrome(head), what is the type of head? What does the pallindrome function return? Doesn't the compiler complain a lot? Listen to the compiler, it will know what the problem with your code is. And enable even more warning messages, and treat them as errors.

@Someprogrammerdude I edited and added all the warnings my compiler raised. I will try to resolve them and get back to you. Thankyou.

@Mridul Hemrajani, struct node* create(head) needs to be be something like struct node* create(struct node *head_address).

In your function pallindrome, after the while loop, the q variable value is NULL. Then you try to do q->data. That's not going to end well.

In the create function definition, the type of head defaults to int. This is an old-style (K&R) function definition that will no longer be supported in C23. You should define it using a prototype instead.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I am reading your code and wish to know what is the defintion for your node. like having:
struct structure_name {
data_type member_name1;
data_type member_name1;
....
....
};
that way probably we can understand the problem better
